# Typo3 backend error: "The requested page does not exist"

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

When I click on backend tabs I keep getting this error screen. I already created the robot.txt file but it is still showing up.

> `TYPO3\CMS\Core\Error\Http\PageNotFoundException`
> The requested page does not exist

[image: PageNotFoundException]

Comment: robots.txt files are solely for search engines and have nothing to do with your problem. Maybe you mean a .htaccess file, but none is necessary for the TYPO3 backend to work. Regarding your problem: does the error occur for every module in the left menu? Does the install tool work? (https://yourdomain.tld/typo3/install.php) And by the way, I'd suggest to update your installation to TYPO3 9.5.21 immediately to mitigate several security issues.

Comment: I don't know if its relevant but this error also appear when you try to access a page in the frontend and didn't exist's and you have a password protection in your htaccess.

Comment: This error happen only in backend, and not all the time, but even when i click on the pageTree this error comes up.